# Display drivers for mercury mother board

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I am having **MERCURY KOBIAN PI845GLM-L** mother board and I am looking for Display Drivers for this mother board, I have all the other drivers from Mercury site for this mother board but they have not provided Display Drivers.

Can some one tell me which display drivers to use and from where to download.

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 1):

On that motherboard should be Intel® 82845G Graphics Controller

Try download drivers from Intel - http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intel845g/